# MySQL does not select all data from one table that is Left Join with another table?

Tags: mysql

In one of my **PHP** application, I use left join between two **MySQL** tables using the following query:

```
SELECT bs.question_code, bs.question_english, count( st.id ) sqid
FROM bs_qbank_question bs
LEFT JOIN bs_qbank_question_study_link st
  ON bs.id = st.question_id
```

The problem is, it selects only those rows from `bs_qbank_question` that have at least one row in `bs_qbank_question_study_link` table. If there is no data for a particular row of `bs_qbank_question` in `bs_qbank_question_study_link` then that row is not selected.

But I need to select each row from `bs_qbank_question` and also need one column for each row from `bs_qbank_question_study_link` as **count the total occurrence of that row**.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my query and how can I replace `count( st.id )` as 0 if there is no data for any row?
- Thanks

Comment: join outer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578/2845029

Comment: and also add group by at end of the query for eg: **GROUP BY bs.question_code,bs.question_english**

Comment: See COALESCE().